# Are CBCentral and CBPeripheral identifiers the same for one device

Tags: ios, iphone, core-bluetooth, cbcentralmanager, cbperipheral

The title explains it all. All I want to know is that if a device is being used as a peripheral and a central and gets near another device being used as a peripheral and a central, **would the peripheral manager and central manager on each device see the same "identifier" property on the CBPeripheral and the CBCentral objects corresponding to the to the other device in the area?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no official statement but experience shows that a remote device is identified by a single UUID. That is, the CBPeripheral and the CBCentral corresponding to the same remote device will have the same UUID. However, these values will be different on each host. E.g. an iPhone will never have the same UUID on different iOS devices that discover it.

Comment: What about the across OSes, platforms (Android / iOS), devices? Will the same CBPeripheral identifier always be consistent? (Say for example storing it on server to identify it when connected to other devices?) That is assuming it is never changed on the BT device side...

Comment: @Rich The CBPeripheral UUID is internally generated and used by iOS. There is no such thing on Android. The MAC address could be a natural unique identifier but you have no access to that in iOS. You need to develop your own identification mechanism to achieve cross platform identifiers, possibly based on proprietary characteristics.

Comment: Ah ok - yeah I was thinking MAC but yeah no way of access that! Thanks for your help tho!